# Ghost scroll bars on Chrome with Windows 7

Tags: fancybox

Wondering if you've seen any issues using fancybox on Windows7 with Chrome where you get ghost scroll bars?  [See this image](http://ttp://avwxworkshops.com/etips/images/Ghost-Scroll-Bars.gif).

This actually doesn't happen with Chrome under Vista.

If you look [here](http://avwxworkshops.com/etips/images/Overflow-Attribute.gif), the overflow attribute is overridden/changed to scroll by something.  Setting it to hidden using Firebug, makes the ghost scroll bars disappear. I've got the attribute set to hidden in the code, but something is evidently overriding the attribute to scroll.

Any ideas how to get rid of these ghost scroll bars?

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround would be to use `!important` in your css to force them to go away.

Comment: .fancybox-inner{
 overflow:hidden!important; --did that as shown here and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: There were several css entries.  Found the actual one that was giving me the issue and by adding !important, it fixed this error...thanks a bunch!!!!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Not the best way of doing it but if it works then hey! All good.